# ASPX - UpdatePanel stretches body define height

Tags: html, css, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm redesigning a web site (using VisualStudio 2015 and C#) mostly by redoing all the CSS and stumbled into a problem. I'm including the CSS and a simple HTML to simplify. The actual HTML is behaving properly, the content of the page doesn't exceed the browser height. To see what happens with the ASPX, uncomment lines 88 and 355 of the HTML (the UpdatePanel), the content will exceed browser height. Is there a solution to make the UpdatePanel version to behave like it wasn't there?

[Without UpdatePanel](https://www.jvazcarvalho.net/NoUpdatePanel.html)

[With UpdatePanel](https://www.jvazcarvalho.net/WithUpdatePanel.html)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Condomínio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="./MapaPagamentos.aspx" id="form1">
            <div class="aspNetHidden">
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__EVENTTARGET"
                    id="__EVENTTARGET"
                    value=""
                />
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__EVENTARGUMENT"
                    id="__EVENTARGUMENT"
                    value=""
                />
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__LASTFOCUS"
                    id="__LASTFOCUS"
                    value=""
                />
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__VIEWSTATE"
                    id="__VIEWSTATE"
                    value="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"
                />
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                var theForm = document.forms["form1"];
                if (!theForm) {
                    theForm = document.form1;
                }
                function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
                    if (!theForm.onsubmit || theForm.onsubmit() != false) {
                        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                        theForm.submit();
                    }
                }
                //]]>
            </script>

            <script
                src="/CondominioDemo/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZJkd1okuUKDBMR_ybfZb3RSlUUSjZCAfoNsrE6K0tzPYalRgDqUV5JPYaHVBNKY9LQ2&amp;t=637729621680000000"
                type="text/javascript"
            ></script>

            <script
                src="/CondominioDemo/ScriptResource.axd?d=NJmAwtEo3Ipnlaxl6CMhvmA-IOG0qw2-sTwiBBy8vNT6VPdiwm5R7e76EyJka1l_yhQWFOZoqwofcNnUPcyZqZeSg7m72O-hlVlBM9j6-sLJRzsjHLO4UrdLadOjVzcCmw3EjjaNzwzAVg9ABsuvIWdTdTRHm2Vk4cRov8-cii01&amp;t=ffffffffd202a464"
                type="text/javascript"
            ></script>
            <script
                src="/CondominioDemo/ScriptResource.axd?d=dwY9oWetJoJoVpgL6Zq8OKovRNsVstQscVwIQcZgX1KzaScRWnz6wSJkDdYXLVcOpbbCQVzEhI1yl2nr7QNZHyOp4PDx67jIuuH3ZUMJ8rnvkbFnAadn5OqcXZKnQkDJwrAIcno8_ThS8OcZOZlerIMowSYTmoMksrQ3nNLzQok1&amp;t=ffffffffd202a464"
                type="text/javascript"
            ></script>
            <div class="aspNetHidden">
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"
                    id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"
                    value="D2CA929D"
                />
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"
                    id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"
                    value=""
                />
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="__EVENTVALIDATION"
                    id="__EVENTVALIDATION"
                    value="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"
                />
            </div>
            <!--<div id="UpdatePanel1">-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize(
                        "ctl00$ScriptManager1",
                        "form1",
                        ["tctl00$UpdatePanel1", "UpdatePanel1"],
                        [],
                        [],
                        90,
                        "ctl00"
                    );
                    //]]>
                </script>

                <header class="header-main">
                    <nav>
                        <a href="Default.aspx">Início</a>
                        <div class="subnav">
                            <a href="#">Mapas</a>
                            <div class="subnav-content">
                                <a href="MapaPagamentos.aspx">Pagamentos</a>
                                <a href="MapaReceitas.aspx">Receitas</a>
                                <a href="MapaDespesas.aspx">Despesas</a>
                                <a href="Charts.aspx">Gráficos</a>
                                <a href="MapaBalanco.aspx">Balanço</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subnav">
                            <a href="#">Movimentos</a>
                            <div class="subnav-content">
                                <a href="Receitas.aspx">Receitas</a>
                                <a href="Despesas.aspx">Despesas</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">Documentos</a>
                        <div class="subnav">
                            <a href="#">Consultas</a>
                            <div class="subnav-content">
                                <a href="ManSaldos.aspx">Saldos</a>
                                <a href="Administracoes.aspx"
                                    >Administ. / Contactos</a
                                >
                                <a href="Condominos.aspx">Condóminos</a>
                                <a href="ManCalendario.aspx">Agenda</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subnav">
                            <a href="#">Admin.</a>
                            <div class="subnav-content">
                                <div class="subsubnav">
                                    <a href="#">Tabelas</a>
                                    <div class="subsubnav-content">
                                        <a href="ManFraccoes.aspx">Fracções</a>
                                        <a href="ManCondominos.aspx"
                                            >Condóminos</a
                                        >
                                        <a href="ManUtilizadores.aspx"
                                            >Utilizadores</a
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="subsubnav">
                                    <a href="#">Valores</a>
                                    <div class="subsubnav-content">
                                        <a href="ManPrestacoes.aspx">Quotas</a>
                                        <a href="Orcamentos.aspx">Orçamentos</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="subsubnav">
                                    <a href="#">Utilitários</a>
                                    <div class="subsubnav-content">
                                        <a href="PrevisoesMensais.aspx"
                                            >Act. Prev. Receitas</a
                                        >
                                        <a href="RenomDocs.aspx">Renom. Docs</a>
                                        <a href="ManTabela.aspx"
                                            >Edit. Tabelas</a
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <a
                        id="usrname"
                        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$usrname&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
                        >Utilizador: João Carvalho</a
                    >
                </header>

                <header>
                    <p></p>
                    <h2>Pagamentos</h2>
                    <div>
                        <label>Tipo:&nbsp;</label>
                        <select
                            name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TipoRecSelect"
                            onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TipoRecSelect\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)"
                            id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TipoRecSelect"
                        >
                            <option selected="selected" value="ORD">
                                Ordin&#225;ria
                            </option>
                            <option value="EXT">Extraordin&#225;ria</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Exercicio de:&nbsp;</label>
                        <select
                            name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$YearSelect"
                            onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$YearSelect\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)"
                            id="ContentPlaceHolder1_YearSelect"
                        >
                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            <option value="2021">2021</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="2022">
                                2022
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="image"
                            name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnExcel"
                            id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnExcel"
                            title="Abrir em Excel"
                            src="images/microsoft-excel-logo-bold.svg"
                        />
                        <input
                            type="image"
                            name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnPrint"
                            id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnPrint"
                            title="Imprimir"
                            src="images/printer-bold.svg"
                            onclick="CallPrint();"
                        />
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </header>
                <article>
                    <div>
                        <table
                            class="customGrid"
                            cellspacing="0"
                            cellpadding="3"
                            rules="all"
                            border="1"
                            id="ContentPlaceHolder1_IncomeGrid"
                            style="border-collapse: collapse"
                        >
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Frac&#231;&#227;o</th>
                                <th scope="col">Andar</th>
                                <th scope="col">Cond&#243;mino</th>
                                <th scope="col">Transitado</th>
                                <th scope="col">Jan.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fev.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Mar.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Abr.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Mai.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Jun.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Jul.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Ago.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Set.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Out.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nov.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Dez.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Saldo</th>
                                <th scope="col">A Transitar</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">A</td>
                                <td align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">Loja (13D)</td>
                                <td align="left" style="white-space: nowrap">(Quiosque Sol&#225;tia)</td>
                                <td title="2022-01-01 € 0.00 Posição do ano anterior" align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">...</td>
                                <td align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">...<td align="left" style="white-space: nowrap">...</td>
                                <td title="2022-01-01 € 0.00 Posição do ano anterior" align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right" style="white-space: nowrap">0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="font-weight: bold">
                                    Total
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="right">-2,903.10</td>
                                <td align="right">400.00</td>
                                <td  align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td  align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">0.00</td>
                                <td align="right">-2,503.10</td>
                                <td align="right">-11,023.10</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <footer>
                    <a
                        id="btnLogin"
                        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$btnLogin&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
                        >Alterar senha / dados</a
                    >
                    <a
                        id="btnCal"
                        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$btnCal&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
                        >Tarefas</a
                    >
                    <a
                        id="btnAdmin"
                        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$btnAdmin&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
                        >Administração / Contacto</a
                    >
                    <a
                        id="btnLegal"
                        href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$btnLegal&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
                        >Informação legal</a
                    >
                </footer>
            <!--</div>-->
            <div id="UpdateProgress1" style="display: none">
                <div class="Warning">
                    <span style="position: relative; top: 50%"> AGUARDE</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                    $create(
                        Sys.UI._UpdateProgress,
                        {
                            associatedUpdatePanelId: "UpdatePanel1",
                            displayAfter: 1,
                            dynamicLayout: true,
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        $get("UpdateProgress1")
                    );
                });
                //]]>
            </script>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
                (function () {
                    function refreshCSS() {
                        var sheets = [].slice.call(
                            document.getElementsByTagName("link")
                        );
                        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                        for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                            var elem = sheets[i];
                            var parent = elem.parentElement || head;
                            parent.removeChild(elem);
                            var rel = elem.rel;
                            if (
                                (elem.href && typeof rel != "string") ||
                                rel.length == 0 ||
                                rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet"
                            ) {
                                var url = elem.href.replace(
                                    /(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/,
                                    ""
                                );
                                elem.href =
                                    url +
                                    (url.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") +
                                    "_cacheOverride=" +
                                    new Date().valueOf();
                            }
                            parent.appendChild(elem);
                        }
                    }
                    var protocol =
                        window.location.protocol === "http:"
                            ? "ws://"
                            : "wss://";
                    var address =
                        protocol +
                        window.location.host +
                        window.location.pathname +
                        "/ws";
                    var socket = new WebSocket(address);
                    socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
                        if (msg.data == "reload") window.location.reload();
                        else if (msg.data == "refreshcss") refreshCSS();
                    };
                    if (
                        sessionStorage &&
                        !sessionStorage.getItem(
                            "IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer"
                        )
                    ) {
                        console.log("Live reload enabled.");
                        sessionStorage.setItem(
                            "IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer",
                            true
                        );
                    }
                })();
            } else {
                console.error(
                    "Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading."
                );
            }
            // ]]>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
form {
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #990000;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content min-content minmax(0, 1fr) min-content min-content;
    column-gap: 5px;
    row-gap: 10px;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}

body::after {
    background-image: url("images/Fachada.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 00px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.header-main {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 5px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #c8c2c2;
}

nav {
    align-content: center;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #c8c2c2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.subnav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.subsubnav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.subnav-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.subsubnav-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
    display: block;
    background-color: #afafaf;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: all 2.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 2.5s;
}
.subsubnav:hover .subsubnav-content {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #a1a1a1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: all 2.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 2.5s;
}

.UpdatePanel1 {
    display: block;
}

article {
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #990000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    height: 100%;
}

aside {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px;
    grid-row: 4/5;
}
aside a:link {
    font-size: 10px;
}
aside a:link::first-letter {
    font-size: 11px;
}

footer {
    margin: 5px 5px 20px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
    align-self: flex-end;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #c8c2c2;
}
footer a:link {
    font-size: 9px;
}
footer a:link::first-letter {
    font-size: 10px;
}

header {
    margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background-color: #c8c2c2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}

a img {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
a img:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: scale(2.5, 2.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5, 2.5); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(2.5, 2.5);
}

a span {
    display: none;
}
a:hover span {
    display: block;
    right: 1vw;
    margin-top: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #afafaf;
    color: #990000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a:link,
button,
a:visited,
.dynamic {
    padding: 5px 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    gap: 20px;
    color: #990000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: unset;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: #990000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
a:link::first-letter {
    font-size: 14px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

select {
    border: 2px solid #990000;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #990000;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.customGrid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.customGrid td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to disable row-gap?

```
html, body, form {
 /* row-gap: 0px;*/
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t make any difference. If I set it to 100px it works but creates a 100px space on the top of the page. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Well, can you remove the height: 100%; part on line 111 in the "style1.css" file and try?

Comment: Without line 111 it won't fill the entire browser window, the objective is to get the bottom link buttons on the bottom of the window.